# ASP.NET form that shows a variable amount of rows and columns for checkbox inputs

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, forms, multiple-columns

I'm trying to write code that allows me to do the following:

- Select a **Project** to write tasks for.
- Add a new **input row** on a button click.
- Write out a **Task** *"Window Cleaning"*
- Select a **Task Type** *"Cleaning"*
- Write out a **max time in minutes** for executing the task
- Based on the **Project** *StartDate* and *EndDate*, show project duration in months with checkboxes
- Check the checkboxes in which months the task should be executed
- Add new **input rows** on a button click.
- And finally save all of this to a database

[How I envision the screen looking like (X's are checked boxes)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hU4j4.png)

Now I do have quite a bit of knowledge of how to work most of this out.. But I'm really lost at the part of how I can draw the form. I would appreciate some pointers to the right direction on this.

Simple Controller:

```
public TaskplannerController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new TaskplannerViewModel();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(TaskplannerViewModel model)
    {
        model.ProjectDurationInMonths = model.GetProjectDuration();
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

With ViewModel:

```
public class TaskplannerViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Types;
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Projects;
    public IEnumerable<DateTime> ProjectDurationInMonths;

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string TaskDescription { get; set; }
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    public int MaxTimeInMinutes { get; set; }     

    public EditPoTaakViewModel()
    {
        PopulateSelectLists();
    }  

    private void PopulateSelectLists()
    {
        var taskType = new TaskType();
        TaskTypes = type.GetAll();

        var project = new Project();
        Projects = project.GetAll();
    }

    public IEnumerable<DateTime> GetProjectDuration()
    {
        var project = new Project();
        var selectedProject = project.Get(ProjectId);
        DateTime startDate = selectedProject.StartDate;
        DateTime endDate= selectedProject.endDate;

        while(startDate <= endDate)
        {
            yield return startDate;
            startDate = startDate.AddMonths(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use jquery or javascript to draw the form

Answer (score 0):

i think the asp Repeater could be what yoou need.

It would look like somthing like this:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
           <tr class="Headertemplate">                                                                               
              <th style="display:none;">ID</th>            
              <th>Task</th>
              <th>Type</th>
              <th>Max time in minutes</th>
              <th>Month</th> 
           </tr>            
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
           <tr class="Itemtemplate">                                                             
              <td><asp:Label Text="text" runat="server" /></td>
              <td>
                  <asp:DropDownList runat="server">
                      <asp:ListItem Text="text1" />
                      <asp:ListItem Text="text2" />
                  </asp:DropDownList>
              </td>
              <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" /></td>
              <td><asp:CheckBox Text="text" runat="server" /></td>
              <td></td>
           </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>        
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```